# Script to force IE8 cache behaviour

Tags: javascript, caching, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

in IE8, there's an option on cache developer tools called "refresh always from server". Is it possible to have some javascript or similar to force this behaviour or I have to do it always manually?

I've tried

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

but the refreshing issue in my application seems to be resolved only by checking "refresh always from server" on cache options panel.

Thanks

Comment: Pragma targets the HTTP 1.0 specification.  You may want to try using `Cache-Control` instead.  See [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can do:

> $.ajaxSetup({
>       cache: false
>   });

which has solved many IE8 caching issues for me when using jquery + ajax.

Otherwise, you could use a "cache-breaker" by appending a unique number to the end of the .js uri. Like so:

> http://mysite.com/myscript.js?=_11232131231323

Of course, the unique # could be a DateTime() that is unique on every page request.