# no-cache script without using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, userscripts, no-cache

Hello I am trying to create a script which inserts into any webpage a **meta tag to force no-cache**.

Currently this is my code and **I dont want to use Jquery** (as shown in [Script to force IE8 cache behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477414/script-to-force-ie8-cache-behaviour)).

```
var MAXlen = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].childNodes.length; 
//Get the length of childnodes of head.

while(MAXlen--)
{
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].childNodes[MAXlen+1] = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].childNodes[MAXlen]; 
//store every node one place after.

 if(MAXlen == 0)
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">';
 //place this hmtlcode into the first element of head.
 break;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly is your problem? Do you get an error? If so, provide information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ... prepend without JQuery:

```
parent.insertBefore(child, parent.firstChild);
```

parentNode.insertBefore(newChild, refChild);

Inserts the node `newChild` as a child of `parentNode` before the existing child node `refChild`. (Returns `newChild`.)

If `refChild` is null, `newChild` is added at the end of the list of children. Equivalently, and more readably, use `parentNode.appendChild(newChild)`.

In this case, you wouldn't need to loop through as in the code you presented.

**UPDATE**:

Try this with your code ...

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.httpEquiv = "Pragma";
meta.content = "no-cache";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
head.insertBefore(meta, head.firstChild);
```

1. First, build the meta tag as a node.
2. Then, capture the head tag as a variable.
3. Using the variable, insert the node before the first child.

**COMMENTS**:

- Tested functional in Chrome.
- Tested functional in IE8 with console warning: "The code on this page disabled back and forward caching"

Comment: Right idea; not enough detailed code to help the newbie OP.  Show *exactly* how to add the meta tag. (Not that this approach would work in most browsers; not sure about IE8 (and don't care about IE8).)

Comment: Added the code to show this working.  Tested in Chrome.

Comment: Correct code but beware of 2 important caveats: (1) The question is about IE8. Doesn't necessarily matter if it works on Chrome. (2) You can use JS to add `<meta>` tags, but (¿most?) browsers will not actually parse a `<meta>` tag added that way. IE8 *might* be an exception; doubt it.

Comment: Tested functional in IE8 ... "The code on this page disabled back and forward caching"  Thanks for checking and reminding me.

Comment: Well then, it appears that IE8 *does* parse dynamically added `<meta>` tags. Good job!

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem perfectly! I didnt know there was a way to get the firstChild so fast. I was trying to write into the webpage using document.write and it removed all the webpage instead of the lines i wrote. I am still a newbie and i am surprised everyday from people like you :)

Comment: Glad I could help ... and I am just as surprised, as well, each day!